# Как открыть для чтения файл из папки ресурсов

Tags: java, файлы, jar

хочу прочесть текстовый файл cs.json из папки resources.

```
final Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("cs.json").toURI()));
        for (String line : (Iterable<String>) () -> lines.iterator()) {
            s+=line;
        }
        lines.close();
```

в IDE все работает. когда упаковываю в jar получаю FileNotFoundExceptin. Как указать путь чтобы в jar прочесть текстовый файл из папки resources?

Comment: файл в jar находится?

Comment: да, в корне лежит

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте вместо `getResource` метод `getResourceAsStream`.

Код будет такой:

```
InputStream is = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("cs.json");
```

Comment: Спасибо, открыл
'InputStream is = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("cs.json");'

Comment: @StasNilobop отлично =)