# Получение информации о файле из собственного JAR пакета

Tags: java, классы, eclipse, jar

Как получить доступ к любому файлу из собственного исполняемого JAR пакета как к любому внешнему файлу? Интересует: размер файла, хэш сумма, бинарный доступ (опционально).

В не компилированном проекте Eclipse этот код работает отлично:

```
public class HashcodeTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        File file = new File("java/com/myproject/Config.class"); 
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file.getPath())); 

        String buf = "";

        while (in.readLine() != null)
            buf += in.readLine();

        in.close();

        String hash = String.valueOf(buf.hashCode());

        System.out.print("result: " + buf + "\n");
        System.out.print("size: " + buf.length() + "\n");
        System.out.print("hashcode: " + buf.hashCode() + "\n");
    }

}
```

Но после компиляции в консоли отображается ошибка "не найден файл". Как правильно вызвать внутренний файл?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как открыть для чтения файл из папки ресурсов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/556152/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ нашёл самостоятельно.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class ResourceReader
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            int ch;
            String buf = "";

            InputStream inputStream = ResourceReader.class.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/com/myproject/Config.class");

            while ((ch = inputStream.read()) != -1)
                buf += ((char)ch);

            System.out.print("size: " + buf.length() + "\n");
            System.out.print("hashcode: " + buf.hashCode() + "\n");

            inputStream.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```